# When adding subdomain it's redirecting back to main domain

Tags: apache, xampp, subdomain

Have spent ages trying to figure this out, we're looking to add cloud.domainname.co.nz, the records are all setup, however when you search cloud.domainname.co.nz, it shows you the domainname.co.nz website, and not the one where the directory is set?

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs"
ServerName domain.co.nz
<Directory "C:/xampp/htdocs">
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks ExecCGI Includes
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
Redirect permanent / https://domain.co.nz/

SSLEngine on
SSLCertificateFile C:\xampp\apache\conf\domain.co.nz.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile C:\xampp\apache\conf\domain.co.nz.key
SSLCertificateChainFile C:\xampp\apache\conf\domain.co.nz.ca-bundle
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/cloud"
    ServerName cloud.domain.co.nz
    ServerAlias cloud.domain.co.nz
    <Directory "C:/xampp/cloud">
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Have gone through many other peoples questions/answers and after trying those I still wasn't able to get it working properly, can't figure out why!!

I've also noticed people show their vhosts when trying to figure out similar issues so I've put it below..

```
127.0.0.1       cloud.localhost
127.0.0.1       domain.co.nz
127.0.0.1       cloud.domain.co.nz
```

Answer (score 0):

I solve it by adding this to the virtual host configuration

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
NameVirtualHost *:443

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "D:/htdocs/"
    ServerName localhost
</VirtualHost>
```

NameVirtualHost is so we can use the same port for multiple virtual hosts configurations. Setting up the usual domain for localhost is the key here. I am not sure why, but it solves the bug.